# Question about Matlab: passing strings as split parameters to function

Tags: string, function, matlab

Hey there,
I have the following problem:
I have a string in matlab:

```
str='foo bar'
```

which I want to use for a certain command:

```
mex(..., str)
```

which does NOT work since mex handles `str` as ONE parameter (thus as `mex(..., 'foo bar')`). How to do this, that matlab recognizes it as a function call like that:

```
mex(..., 'foo', 'bar')
```

I don't this hardcoded on this certain example with 2 Parameters, it could also come a time where the strings expands to `str='foo bar blupp'` -> pass as `mex(..., 'foo', 'bar', 'blupp')`.

Thanks!

Comment: Okay I did it now myself like the following: Initialize a variable with `mex(..., ` than loop over all single parameters in `str` and append them to the string. Than eval the string as command!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [strread](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/strread.html) to convert to a cell array, and then `{:}` indexing to expand that back to a "comma separated list".

```
>> x = 'foo bar baz'
x =
foo bar baz
>> xc = strread( x, '%s' )
xc = 
    'foo'
    'bar'
    'baz'
>> fprintf( 'Hello: %s\n', xc{:} )
Hello: foo
Hello: bar
Hello: baz
```

Where the last line is exactly equivalent to

```
fprintf( 'Hello: %s\n', 'foo', 'bar', 'baz' )
```

Comment: There's nearly always a way to avoid "eval".

Comment: Yeah you just have to know how. I didn't know the `{:}` syntax and don't know how to search for something like that. How is this named? Because even after knowiing the command, I want to read about it but google doesn't recognize it when searching for `matlab {:}`

Comment: @Col Heather: You have to search the term "comma separated list", which should get you to [this MATLAB documentation page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/br2js35-1.html).

Comment: OKay thanks. And just for future searches on this thread topic: `strread` will be replaced by `textscan` -> http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/textscan.html